# PHP select number from database

Tags: php, button, share

Here is my whole code and it works but i cannot figure out how do i make just to work on the current pressed button with this code its sharing all the tickets...

```
$user = getUserData('users', 'Username');
    $sql = "SELECT `Uplata`, `Dobivka`, `match1`, `match2`, `match3`, `match4`, `match5`, `match6`, `match7`, `match8`, `match9`, `match10`, `match11`, `match12`, `match13`, `match14`, `match15`, `match16`, `tip1`, `tip2`, `tip3`, `tip4`, `tip5`, `tip6`, `tip7`, `tip8`, `tip9`, `tip10`, `tip11`, `tip12`, `tip13`, `tip14`, `tip15`, `tip16`, `ticket_id`, `isActive`, `isShared` FROM `kladilnica` WHERE `Username`='$user'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $count = 0;
    $uplata_total = 0;

    if($result === false) {
        echo "<b>Could not connect to database.</b>";
        trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    } else {
        if($result->num_rows == 0) {
            echo "<b>You do not have any tickets.</b>";
        } else if($result->num_rows >= 1) {
            $count = $count + 1;
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                if($result->num_rows != empty($row['match1'])) {
                    $uplata_total = $row["Uplata"];
                    $dobivka_total = $row["Dobivka"];
                    $ticket_id = $row["ticket_id"];
                    $is_active = $row["isActive"];
                    $shared = $row["isShared"];
                    if($is_active == 1) {
                        echo "<form action='home.php' method='POST'>";
                        echo "<table id='t02' style='margin-bottom: 10px;'><tr><th colspan='2'><input type='submit' name='share' class='share_button' value='Share'/></a></th></tr>";
                        echo "<tr><th colspan='2'>Ticket ".$count." <a style='position: relative; left: 69px;'>Ticket ID: ".$ticket_id."</a></th></tr>";
                        echo "
                                <tr><td>".$row["match1"]."</td><td>".$row["tip1"]."</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row["match2"]."</td><td>".$row["tip2"]."</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row["match3"]."</td><td>".$row["tip3"]."</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row["match4"]."</td><td>".$row["tip4"]."</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row["match5"]."</td><td>".$row["tip5"]."</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row["match6"]."</td><td>".$row["tip6"]."</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row["match7"]."</td><td>".$row["tip7"]."</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row["match8"]."</td><td>".$row["tip8"]."</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row["match9"]."</td><td>".$row["tip9"]."</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row["match10"]."</td><td>".$row["tip10"]."</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row["match11"]."</td><td>".$row["tip11"]."</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row["match12"]."</td><td>".$row["tip12"]."</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row["match13"]."</td><td>".$row["tip13"]."</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row["match14"]."</td><td>".$row["tip14"]."</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row["match15"]."</td><td>".$row["tip15"]."</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row["match16"]."</td><td>".$row["tip16"]."</td></tr>
                            ";
                        echo "<tr><th colspan='2'>Total Bet: $uplata_total</th></tr>";
                        echo "<tr><th colspan='2'>Total Win: $dobivka_total</th></tr>";
                        echo "</table>";
                        echo "</form>";
                        $count++;
                    }
                }

                if(isset($_POST['share'])) {
                    if($shared == 0) {
                        echo "Ticket shared sucessfully.";
                        $sql = "UPDATE `kladilnica` SET `isShared`=1 WHERE `ticket_id`='$ticket_id'";
                        $return = $conn->query($sql);
                    } else if($shared == 1) {
                        echo $ticket_id;
                        echo "Ticket already shared!";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $conn->close();
```

BTW if someone know a better way of sharing process please share it with me :)

Comment: try checking for `$shared === 1` instead of `$shared == 1`. Not sure about this but worth a try.

Comment: Have you tried seeing what `$row["isShared"]` returns on a row which should show `0`? Also, if you are only selecting one value (`SELECT isShared FROM....`) then perhaps the value `$row` isn't an array and therefore `$shared = $row`?

Comment: yes the `$row["isShared"]` is returning 0

Comment: Anyone with other solution ?

Comment: Question edited, now help if you can :)

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to separate your markup logic from the data.

Comment: @Marc How can i make that ?

Comment: You have plenty of frameworks available: [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/); [Code Igniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter) and more that are heavily used and tested. Good aspect for you is that DB transactions should be simpler.